# One class override the property of another class

Tags: html, css, icons

In the code given below, i want to display the font-size property on the `class:  flip-menu-main-icon` but which is overridden by `font-size property` on `class fa`.
how can I solve this problem?
**HTML Code**:

```css
    .fa {
        display: inline-block;
        font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
        font-size: inherit;
        text-rendering: auto;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
    .flip-menu-main-icon {
        /* margin-left: 10%; */
        font-size: 18px;
        float: none;
        line-height: 2.5rem;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        min-width: 1.5rem;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
<i class="flip-menu-main-icon fa fa-glass "></i><span class="flip-menu-text">Dashboard</span>
```

Comment: `.fa.flip-menu-main-icon`, use this

Comment: be specific when giving attributes to classes. If you wanted to add a class to your <li> tag then in your css it should be like `li > .flip-menu-main-icon {//some style here;}`

Comment: @vivek   you are correct bro,i got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this class

```
.fa.flip-menu-main-icon {
    font-size: 29px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not be using external css.

Please find the code below:

HTML- **index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">  
</head>
<body>
    <i class="flip-menu-main-icon fa fa-glass "></i><span class="flip-menu-text">Dashboard</span>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS - **custom.css**

```
.flip-menu-main-icon {
  /* margin-left: 10%; */
  font-size: 18px;
  float: none;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 1.5rem;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: sorry,i'm using external CSS

Comment: then you must make sure the order you link your css are right. then only it will override automatically... like here first bootstrap, then font awesome, then your custom css...